# Spring Data - Spring Repository: selecting distinct values for a class attribute

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have the following

```
@Entity
public class Restaurant{

    @ManyToOne
    private City c;
    // more
}

@Entity
public class City{

    private String name;
    // more
}
```

I also have a repository

```
public interface RestaurantRepository extends JPARepository<Restaurant, Long> {
// something to put here
}
```

===EDIT====
I have the list of ALL cities, but only some of them are associated to restaurants.

I need to write a method in such respository to extract all cities that are referred by a Restaurant.

In SQL I would just do the following:

```
SELECT CITY.id, CITY.name FROM CITY WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(city_id) FROM RESTAURANT)
```

Is there a way to obtain the same result using the name conventions as of http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html ?

Thanks.

Comment: A Restaurant has a relationship to **one** city according to your mapping so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I Updated my question to clarify. I have a list of ALL cities. I have restaurants coming only from SOME cities. I would like to know which cities do not have any restaurants associated. Therefore, I want to extract all distinct cities from the Restaurant table. In sql, I would just write "SELECT distinct(city_id) from restaurant". To extract the full city record, I would just join with the city table. This last thing is what I want to get: the list of all cities for which no restaurants were stored.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not see any support for the IS [NOT] EMPTY operator listed in Spring Data's documentation around query creation strategy, you can try manually defining a JPQL  query:

```
public interface CityRepository extends JPARepository<City, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT c FROM CITY c WHERE c.restaurants IS EMPTY")
    List<City> findCitiesWithNoRestaurants();

}
```

which I'm guessing will translate to the native SQL you gave as an example.

Otherwise looks like you would need to find a list of cities with Restraunts and then pass that to a method which used the NotIn pattern. This will obviously be less performant than the above.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: That does not seem a viable solution for my context. That's the reason why I am looking to define a method as of paragraph 2.3 of the link I posted, according to JPA method name-based query derivation.

Comment: Well I am obviously still not understanding your question so good luck.

Comment: Because I am binding my database structure to my application. I would strongly avoid that. For example, I need to assume I have a "CITY" table, a "RESTAURANT" table and a "city_id" field in this last table. My domain is actually more complicated than I presented in my question (I have a hierarchy for both restaurants and cities). As long as possible, I would like to avoid native queries. Is there a different path I can follow? Rather than a native query, I would implement the selection of cities at application level.

Comment: Use JPQL then. See update. Otherwise as Spring Data query resolution does not appear to support the IS [NOT] EMPTY operator, looks like you wiould need to take the  performance hit of multiple queries and use IN/NOTIN.